# \\* and \\ \nopagebreak not working as expected

Tags: line-breaking, page-breaking

I need an empty line between two paragraphs and so as usual I end one of them with `\\`. However that paragraph was at the bottom of a page so the empty line is difficult to see if you don't know to look for it. Searching on line I found two possible solutions `\\*` and `\\ \nopagebreak` however both of these produce the same behavior.

So, I either need to break the page sooner, or have something indicating that a break, other than a page break, has also occurred. However, since the text above it may change (and there is a lot text above it) I don't want to make this a special case. Meaning I don't want to manually force a break in the middle of the paragraph myself, if that is the solution, but rather I want LaTeX to do that.

Comment: Don't end paragraphs with \\. This only give underfull box warnings. If you need space between paragraphs  use \vspace.

Comment: placing `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph will _always_ give bad spacing (tex warns you about badness 10000, which is the maximum value it assigns to any bad box)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never use `\\` at the end of a paragraph.

If you need to add vertical space use `\vspace` or a pre-defined space such as `\bigskip`.

In the document below TeX chooses the page break at the extra space, adding `\nopagebreak` at the point indicated prevents that choice so forcing TeX to take a different page break here it breaks the preceding paragraph taking one line over to the next page followed by the big skip.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}


\begin{document}

\def\z{\stepcounter{enumi}\roman{enumi}\ one two three four five six seven eight nine ten. }
\def\zz{\z\z\z\z\z\z\z Black white blue red green. \z\z}


AAA \zz\zz

BBB \zz\z\z
line a line a line a line a line a line a line a line a line a line a line a 
line b line b line b line b line b line b line b line b line b line b  
line c line c line c line c line c line c line c line c line c line c  

%\nopagebreak
\bigskip

CCC \zz

DDD \zz
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I needed the \nopagebreak first. Also, thanks for pointing out the problem with \\. I've just been ignoring the underfull box warnings since they didn't result in any discernible issues. I made a macro command for \nopagebreak\vspace{\baselineskip} which has the same desired result without the errors or not working the way I think it should.